# What are the possible values of 'gender' field in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently introduced many options for Gender besides male and female. Is there a list of all possible values for 'gender' field in Graph API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I found out. I tried setting custom gender in a test account.

The possible values are still only 'male' and 'female'. When you select a custom gender and then enter one of the custom genders, then there is a field near the bottom with option - What pronoun do you prefer?

[image: Facebook Custom Gender]

Here depending on what you choose the gender field returns 'male' or 'female', irrespective of what you enter in 'Gender'. However, if you choose 'Neutral' then Graph API has no 'gender' field in it.

Answer (score 0):

This article gives a list of all the possible genders they were able to find but they note that Facebook has not published an official list. http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2014/02/13/facebook_custom_gender_options_here_are_all_56_custom_options.html

Comment: I am looking for the codes. These the display values, in graph api the codes could be very different.